# What does "courtesy" mean in "courtesy associate"?

Tags: word-meaning

The Longman dictionary states that *courtesy* can be used as a noun meaning *politeness*, or as an adjective meaning *provided free to a customer or the public*, as in courtesy phone. In job titles such as

> Courtesy associate

Does the word mean an associate who should be polite when dealing with customers, or does it mean an associate who helps customers with their purchased items for free?

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't heard the phrase before, but suspect it may be somewhat dependent on context.

For instance, here is what [Walmart](https://www.job-applications.com/walmart-courtesy-associate/) (from job-applications) says of its job title of the same name:

> **What Does a Walmart Courtesy Associate Do?**
>
> An entry-level job title, the position of Walmart courtesy associate primarily entails retrieving shopping carts from Walmart parking lots. Additional job duties include relieving cashiers, organizing and straightening aisles, and assisting customers when necessary.

In contrast, it seems [Walmart](https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGnewUI/Search/Home/HomeWithPreLoad?PageType=JobDetails&partnerid=25222&siteid=5011&jobid=1222228#jobDetails=1222228_5011) (from BrassRing) also advertises a **courtesy** ***desk*** **associate** job title:

> **Position Summary**
>
> A Courtesy Desk Associate provides friendly and professional Customer Service, represents Company values to the public, ensures proper adherence to Company policies and maintains security in front end operations.

In other words, it seems to be a catch-all term for any number of positions involving customer service and maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

A Courtesy Assistant is usually a very junior, or entry level, position in a supermarket or discount store. The functions can vary from store to store, but they typically include:

- collecting shopping trolleys from the stores car park,
- keeping shelves fully stocked,
- reshelving returned items or items that have been moved from their proper location,
- greeting customers as they enter the store,
- helping to answer customer queries,
- carry out price checks for check-out operators,
- cleaning up spills within the store,
- with some experience they may also relieve staff register staff when they are taking a break,
- etc.

Courtesy in the name implies that their main role is to be nice to the customers. This, of course, is a role of every employee in the store, but more senior staff are usually involved in specific tasks within the store (working at the cash register, managing staff, working in the store rooms, doing administrative tasks, etc), and may not be easily available to help customers.